# new created link is block displayed on localhost

Tags: javascript, html

Need to create a link inside a contenteditable div.

Pls select `https://google.com` and click on the button.

In the example below everything works fine but the same code on my localhost (win7, xampp, chrome) creates the link as a block displayed, like this:

```
lorem ipsum
https://google.com
```

Why this happens and how to create a normal, inline link.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 let a = window.getSelection().toString();
 let ht = "<a contentEditable='false' href = '" + a + "' target = '_blank'>" + a + "</a>";
 document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, ht);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='story' contenteditable>
lorem ipsum https://google.com
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: @j08691, no, console is empty